# How can I redirect sound from Ubuntu desktop to Bravia TV?

Tags: sound

After searching for almost a month for the solution (still unsolved), asking here with a lot of hope.

### Background:

I have a Bravia TV which is connected to my HP computer running Ubuntu 12.04 dual booted with Windows 7. Desktop is having no HDMI port, instead one DIVX and one VGA port. The VGA port is connected to a small monitor and the DIVX port connected to TV with HDMI at the TV end. A male-male 3.5 audio connector connects the audio input port at TV and rear headphone jack at desktop.

### Purpose:

I want to view movies stored in my HDD over my big screen TV.

### Problem:

When I am in Windows, I switch screen from my monitor to TV and view movies, no issues. But now I want to phase out Windows with Ubuntu but only this problem is restricting me. I can switch displays but no sound is coming. First the audio drivers were not present, installed them, checked with headphones and 5.1 speakers, audio is coming but I want it through my TV. Strange thing is that if I unplug my DIVX port, the sound is coming through TV, screen obviously blank and display is coming through my small monitor.

### Alternatives:

If I use audio from my home theatre and display from TV, it solves my purpose, but then I am not utilizing my TV speakers and going towards more electricity bills. I also tried the DLNA way (my TV and Ubuntu desktop is connected to the same router/network) using miniDLNA, Plex, Serviio etc. but each is having some or the other problem.

Comment: you mean DVI not DIVX, right?

Comment: Yes, my bad. It's DVI

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Ubuntu sets the wrong output. Try the following.

Connect your PC to the TV. Then go to `Sound settings`:

[image]

You'll be presented with the following screen:

[image]

From the `Play sound through` select the output device corresponding to your audio jack. The list will be different from the one in the picture above, but if you can't figure out which one the right one you may just try them all (should be something like Analog Stereo Output).

Also be sure that the `Output volume` slider is not zeroed.

Comment: I did this, it shows fine with one entry in the left "Analog Output/Built-in Audio" with full volume slider, still no sound. The test sound command button opens up a pop up window with two speaker icons with butons below, still no sound. If I plug-out the tv audio jack and put my headphone jack in, can hear a female voice saying front left/front right etc.

Answer (score 0):

To quote your response:
"If I plug-out the tv audio jack and put my headphone jack in, can hear a female voice saying front left/front right etc. "

That being the case, you do have output from the computer so I would check the Sony Bravia audio settings.  There might be something there to switch on.

Good Luck